# Applying Euler's characteristic formula on a graph embedded on a Torus

Tags: graph-theory

We know that Euler's characteristic of a Torus is $0$. Suppose, a graph is embeddable in a Torus, e.g., $K_5$, then if we apply Euler's characteristic formula $\chi=v-e+f$ on $K_5$, we should have $\chi=0$. Is there any way to prove $\chi=v-e+f=0$ for any graph that is embeddable in a Torus without knowing the fact that $\chi$ is $0$ for a torus?

Comment: I guess it is not true for an arbitrary graph on a torus. Take for example the one-vertex graph. It still has $v-e+f=1-0+1=2$, basically because it can still be embedded into $\Bbb R^2$. So you have to restrict to graphs, which *use up all of the torus*, whatever this means. For these I think it will be feasible to actually prove the Euler characteristic to be 0 by induction though.

Comment: @JonasLinssen, Could you please explain a little bit what do mean by 'use up all of the torus?'

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t know yet. Informally your embedding should wrap the graph along the horizontal equator as well as through the hole in the middle. If you define a torus as the topological space $\Bbb S^1\times \Bbb S^1$, consider the subspace $\Bbb S^1\times \{1\}\cup\{1\}\times\Bbb S^1$ and turn this into an embedding of a graph by putting some vertices on it, then you may check that the Euler characteristic of this embedding really is 0. Btw note that the resulting graph itself, which looks like two cycles attached together at a single vertex, is still a planar graph.